# estar pensado o estar tonto

Tags: vocabulario

I was told recently "estar pensado" or "estar tonto" means to be vain, in love with oneself etc. I presume this is correct, at least, in a colloquial way. Is that so?

I cannot find reference to it anywhere. A Valencian friend told me this.

Also, what are the more formal ways to express this please?

I found "presumido", "enamorado de sí mismo".

Are there more formal and informal versions? I am interested as I think it is everyday Spanish like we say "big-headed", "swell-headed" etc in English.

Comment: Are you sure about "estar pensado". I've never heard such expression. Maybe it's a regionalism from Valencia. It's not common, at least in Andalusia, where I live.

Comment: _estar tonto_ is certainly used colloquially in that sense. The DLE does not mark it as regional.

Comment: Ok, so in Valencia it means that, if you believe your friend. estar tonto: RAE: 6. adj. coloq. Presumido o vanidoso.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure about the term or the expression that you were looking for, because as I commented "estar pensado" it's not used in my region.

Taking into account the meaning of [swelled-head](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swollen-head) that you can find in the Cambridge dictionary

> If someone has a swollen head (US usually also **swelled head**), that person thinks they are more
> intelligent and more important than they really are

let me offer one of the equivalents in Spanish: [**creido**](https://dle.rae.es/cre%C3%ADdo), that according to the DRAE means

> 1. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Vanidosa, orgullosa o muy pagada de sí misma.

Some synonyms of creído: soberbio, altanero, arrogante, fatuo, cantamañanas. All of them used with **ser** and not estar: (él) es un creído ...

On the expression side we have: **ir de [sobrado](https://www.rae.es/drae2001/sobrado)**. If you check the link, you can verify that it's equivalent to creído but in this case I think that it's most common in Spain to use the verb **ir** instead of ser: (él) va de sobrado

Comment: Thank you. That is all very useful. I believe my Valencian friend used ''estar pensado'' ,I will check with her again. It does sound a bit strange to me.Maybe another reader will know. Thanks for the extra phrases

Comment: [I've never heard an expression like that. such is not much used in these cases.]

Comment: No será "estar pesado"? –¡Estás un poco pesado!– es habitual

Comment: @Danielillo Sí, "estar pesado" es muy común pero no suele usarse en este contexto. Es cuando alguien está resultando molesto [annoying] con un tema o en general, no?

Comment: Tampoco es que yo tenga muy claro el o los adjetivos a los que se refiere el OP, son varios y todos diferentes. Al tipo de "pesado" que me refiero es al de estar "espeso". Solo por poner algo de contexto al "estar pensado" que carece totalmente de sentido.

Comment: it is in fact used in Valencia so I see why not many know it.thank you